# How do I make Kali not sleep from login screen?

Tags: kali-linux

I have Kali installed on Bare Metal to a laptop.

Well within specs:
i7 
32GB memory
500GB SSD
System 76 laptop (2017 model)
Using the default Gnome instance of Kali
All updates ran as of 2019-07-26

When I login, it stays on forever, no issues. I have all power mods turned off. 
I also have it configured to automatically connect to an OpenVPN config.

But I would like it to not sleep after it has been booted and sitting on the login screen. My intent is to allow the laptop to be turned on, once the encryption password has been entered, have an Ethernet cable plugged in and auto-connect to VPN. From there I will simply SSH into the laptop via the VPN connection.

I have checked the BIOS and there are no power options to adjust.

Additionally, after extreme periods of inactivity (over 4 hours) the machine seemingly goes into deep hibernation and requires a hard power cycle to come back to life. Once again, this is only if sitting at the login screen, if any user is logged in, it stays on and runs fine indefinitely.

Any advice?

Comment: Seems this is a duplicate of "[How to disable sleep/suspend at login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/942366/how-to-disable-sleep-suspend-at-login-screen)".

Comment: Voting to move to SuperUser as there is no information security context.

Comment: Please inform us of whether you are using `lightdm`, `gdm3` or `kdm`. You can do this with `apt list --installed | grep .*dm.*`.